# Web API routing with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm trying to work out how to do the routing for the following Web API controller:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    // POST api/MyController/GetAllRows/userName/tableName
    [HttpPost]
    public List<MyRows> GetAllRows(string userName, string tableName)
    {
        ...
    }

    // POST api/MyController/GetRowsOfType/userName/tableName/rowType
    [HttpPost]
    public List<MyRows> GetRowsOfType(string userName, string tableName, string rowType)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

At the moment, I'm using this routing for the URLs:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("AllRows", "api/{controller}/{action}/{userName}/{tableName}",
                    new
                    {
                        userName= UrlParameter.Optional,
                        tableName = UrlParameter.Optional
                    });

routes.MapHttpRoute("RowsByType", "api/{controller}/{action}/{userName}/{tableName}/{rowType}",
                    new
                    {
                        userName= UrlParameter.Optional,
                        tableName = UrlParameter.Optional,
                        rowType= UrlParameter.Optional
                    });
```

but only the first method (with 2 parameters) is working at the moment. Am I on the right lines, or have I got the URL format or routing completely wrong? Routing seems like black magic to me...

Comment: how does one specify a parameter that is NOT optional? I want the first to be required and the second as optional?

Comment: Routing is just more painful IMO doing it in the webapiconfig, see my answer on Attribute Routing with Route

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is your `api/MyController/GetRowsOfType/userName/tableName/rowType` URL will always match the first route so the second is never reached.

Simple fix, register your `RowsByType` route first.

Answer (score 65):

I have seen the **WebApiConfig** get "*out of control"* with **hundreds of routes** placed in it.

Instead I personally prefer [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

**You are making it confusing with POST and GET**

```
[HttpPost]
public List<MyRows> GetAllRows(string userName, string tableName)
{
   ...
}
```

**HttpPost** AND **GetAllRows** ?

**Why not instead do this:**

```
[Route("GetAllRows/{user}/{table}")]
public List<MyRows> GetAllRows(string userName, string tableName)
{
   ...
}
```

OR change to  Route("PostAllRows"    and PostRows   I think that you are truly doing a GET request so the code I show should work for you. Your call from client would be WHATEVER is in the ROUTE , so it WILL FIND your METHOD with GetAllRows,  but the method itself , that name CAN BE anything that you want, so as long as the caller matches the URL in ROUTE, you could put in GetMyStuff for the method if you really wanted to.

**Update:**

I actually prefer to be `explicit` with type of `HTTP methods` 
AND I prefer to match the route params to the method params

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/lead/{vendorNumber}/{recordLocator}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetLead(string vendorNumber, string recordLocator)
{ .... }
```

(the route `lead` does not need to match method name `GetLead` but you will want to keep the same names on the route params and the method params,   even though you can change the order e.g.   put recordLocator before vendorNumber even if the route is the opposite  - I don't do that , as why make it more confusing to look at).

**Bonus**:
Now you can always use **regex** in routes as well,  example

```
[Route("api/utilities/{vendorId:int}/{utilityType:regex(^(?i)(Gas)|(Electric)$)}/{accountType:regex(^(?i)(Residential)|(Business)$)}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetUtilityList(int vendorId, string utilityType, string accountType)
    {
```

Comment: I think `Attribute Routing` is better choice too. +1

Comment: This requires API 2 which isn't always an option.

Comment: This same advice holds true for asp.net core (didn't try regex) but the attribute routing worked for me if i did [Route("~the/things/{thingId}/subthing{id}/save")]/ and [Route("~the/things/{thingId}/subthing{id}/submit")]/